# I am using the R function pairs() and I want to create scatterplots against one specific column

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I am using these lines of code to generate scatterplots between all the combinations of the columns of data: air . Is there any way to choose all the combinations of columns with a specific column? For example if we have 5 columns, I want only the scatterplots for the 3d column such as: 1-3, 2-3, 4-3, 5-3. Not all the combinations.

```
pairs(air, labels = colnames(air), main = "Pairs matrix", pch = 21, 
bg = c("red", "green3", "blue", "yellow"),
upper.panel = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `pairs2()` function from the `TeachingDemos` package. e.g.:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
pairs2( airquality[3], airquality[,c(1,2,4,5) ], panel=panel.smooth)
```

[image]